# In Python, imported function has the same value, but it should not

Tags: python, service

```
import psutil

def check_cpu_usage():
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    if usage > 75:
        print("CPU usage is AWFUL.")
    else:
        print("ok1")

def check_frequency():
    frequency = psutil.cpu_freq()
    if frequency.current > 900:
        print("Frequency is HIGH.")
    else:
        print("ok2")

def check_vmemory():
    vmemory = psutil.virtual_memory()
    if vmemory.percent > 75:
        print("Additional memory is NEEDED.")
    else:
        print("ok3")

def check_disk_usage():
    usaged = psutil.disk_usage('/')
    if usaged.percent > 70:
        print("Disk is going to be FULL.")
    else:
        print("ok4")

def check_battery():
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    if battery.percent < 30:
        print("plug in")
    else:
        print("ok5")
```

It was the `urll.py` file whose `check_vmemory` module has been exported.

```
import os 
import win32serviceutil
import wmi
from urll import check_vmemory

if check_vmemory != "ok3":
    service_name = ['Print Spooler', 'Windows Update', 'HP SI Service']
    for s in service_name:
        win32serviceutil.StopService(s)
```

But the result is the same. Even though I am changing the parameters to see the result, it always act like the `check_vmemory() != "ok3"` is True
What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have `check_vmemory` return a string:

```
def check_vmemory():
  vmemory = psutil.virtual_memory()
  result = ""
  if vmemory.percent > 75:
    print("Additional memory is NEEDED.")
  else:
    print("ok3")
    result = "ok3"
  return result
```

Then call the `check_vmemory` function in your condition (with parentheses `()`)

```
if check_vmemory() != "ok3":
  ...
```

`check_vmemory()` will return either `''` or `'ok3'`. `check_vmemory` is the function itself, so the condition `check_vmemory != 'ok3'` is always `True`.